# Jenkins GitHub Organization building master *and* PRs

Tags: jenkins, github

I'd like to set up a Jenkins "GitHub Organization" project. For branch sources, I'd like to pick "Only branches that are also PRs", but I would like to *also* build one or two white-listed branches. (ie, "master", or "release")

Adding filters cuts down on the list of branches to be built, I want to add some. I could set branch discovery to "All branches", but there's no filter I can specify for also-filed-as-PR, without imposing some branch name convention or something.

So far as I can tell, this means I need to set up two whole Jenkins projects, one with PR discovery, and one with the branch filter for my whitelist. This seems awkward and redundant. Any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found two potential solutions:

This plugin allows you to build certain branches AND any PRs that target those branches:
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SCM+Filter+Branch+PR+Plugin

The Pipeline conditional `changeRequest` allows your Jenkinsfile to test whether it's in a PR, meaning the GitHub Organization could select "All branches".
https://jenkins.io/blog/2018/04/09/whats-in-declarative/